# Flutter Build failure: Not found: 'dart:html' import 'dart:html' http-0.12.2

Tags: java, android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Not sure how landed into the compilation error:

```
Compiler message:                                                       
../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';                                                     
       ^                                                                
../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:34:18: Error: 'HttpRequest' isn't a type.
  final _xhrs = <HttpRequest>{};                                        
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^                                            
../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:58:34: Error: 'Blob' isn't a type.
      var blob = xhr.response as Blob ?? Blob([]);                      
                                 ^^^^                                   
../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:46:15: Error: The method 'HttpRequest' isn't defined for the class 'BrowserClient'.
 - 'BrowserClient' is from 'package:http/src/browser_client.dart' ('../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'HttpRequest'.
    var xhr = HttpRequest();                                            
              ^^^^^^^^^^^                                               
../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:58:42: Error: The method 'Blob' isn't defined for the class 'BrowserClient'.
 - 'BrowserClient' is from 'package:http/src/browser_client.dart' ('../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'Blob'.
      var blob = xhr.response as Blob ?? Blob([]);                      
                                         ^^^^                           
../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart:59:20: Error: The method 'FileReader' isn't defined for the class 'BrowserClient'.
 - 'BrowserClient' is from 'package:http/src/browser_client.dart' ('../../development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.2/lib/src/browser_client.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FileReader'.
      var reader = FileReader();                                        
                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the package caches.

```
pub cache repair
```

and

```
flutter clean
```

Comment: Hello Anirudh, I performed both commands but no luck. Also, I have another flutter project in which I am using http: 0.12.1 and I don't see any error. Any more clues why this specific project is getting the error that too missing dart file.

Comment: It was my mistake of importing wrong file. Removed the browser_client.dart should have not been imported.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into this issue,
This is happening when you import some packages belonging to the web.
In my case, I imported this,

```
import 'package:dio/browser_imp.dart';
```

Because of this the build failure occured. Just remove the import and you're good to go.